# SQL teradata trying to obtain all rows where column has a question mark

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a column(dt) that either contains a date (mo/dd/yr) or a question mark(?). In my where close I'm trying to select only rows where the column has a question mark. I tried the following below and I get an error.

```
where c.dt = '?'
```

The error I get is: `SELECT Failed. 3535:  A character string failed conversion to a numeric value.`

Comment: What is actual data-type of the `dt` column?

Answer (score 4):

The question mark is the string displayed for a `NULL` ;-)

E.g. this is the default in SQL Assistant and BTEQ.

So `dt` is actually a `DATE` column and you need to use:

```
where c.dt IS NULL
```

Btw, you can easily change that default:

- BTEQ: `.SET NULL 'whatever';`
- SQLA: `Tools -> Options -> Data Format -> Display this string for NULL data values`

I usually use `<NULL>` :)

Comment: Silly me - I'm a newbie. Thanks so much :)